# Superscripted and subordinated Terms with chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
2\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}_2\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}^{2-}_{3 \, (aq)}} \arrow \chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny 0},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}_4\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}^{2-}_{6 \, (aq)}} \+ 2\chemfig{e^{-}} 
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

The problem here is that the numbers under sulfur and oxygen are different because the 4 and (aq) are under the 2- but I want it to be beneath the Oxygen exactly like at sulfur. Is there a way?

I tried it with different curly brackets but I didn’t find a solution yet, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `\charge` macro to change the positions of the sulphur indices to match the position of the oxygen indices. Or place the phase and ion charge outside the compound composition using brackets, but I have a feeling you don't want to do that.

So this is an example how the `\charge` macro can be used to reposition the sulphur indices to a lower position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    
    \schemestart
    2\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}\charge{60:-4pt={\scriptsize 2}}{\phantom{..}}\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}^{2-}_{3 \, (aq)}} \arrow \chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny 0},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}\charge{60:-4pt={\scriptsize 4}}{\phantom{..}}\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}^{2-}_{6 \, (aq)}} \+ 2\chemfig{e^{-}} 
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image: lowered indices]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are many superscripts and subscripts on these ions, which makes it confusing.

One way of writing these ions, which is allowed by IUPAC, is to use parentheses around the ions.

And that's enough to solve your problem.

The only changes I made to your code were introducing the parentheses and repositioning the superscripts and subscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
2\chemleft{(}\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny $-$1},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}_2\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}_{3}}\chemright{)^{2-}_{(aq)}}
\arrow
\chemleft{(}\chemfig{\charge{90:3pt={\tiny 0},90:8pt={\tiny $+$5}}{S}_4\charge{80:3pt={\tiny $-$2}}{O}_{6}}\chemright{)^{2-}_{(aq)}} 
\+
2\chemfig{e^{-}} 
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right about the UIPAC recommendations. That was suggested in an earlier question of the OP too as well as in my answer.

Comment: Nice layout, thank you!